# Atalho de código para múltiplos comandos do git

Tags: git, github, cmd, gitlab

Como faço com que apenas um comando sejam executados outros automaticamente no `git`?

**Exemplo:** Ao enviar `git atalho` executar as seguintes instruções:

```
git status
git add Post.txt
git commit -m "aqui coloco uma mensagem"
```

Há como fazer isso sem a necessidade de escrever cada linha separadamente?

Comment: Ambiente Linux ou Windows?

Comment: Luiz, se a resposta resolveu seu problema por gentileza marque a resposta como aceita, caso ainda tenha alguma dúvida pergunte para que possamos esclarecer. Abraço!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Linux:

Crie um `alias` no `terminal`:

**`$`** `alias gitcmd = "git status; git add .; git commit -a -m 'mensagem'; git push;";`

Depois basta chamar o `alias` criado pelo nome:

**`$`** `gitcmd`

Para deixar o comando permanente você deve incluí-lo nos arquivos `.bashrc` ou `.bash_profile`

---

### Windows:

Crie um novo arquivo no editor de texto e salve ele como **`nova-branch.cmd`**

Esse será um arquivo de lotes que pode conter os seguintes comandos:

```
git branch %1 origin/master
git checkout %1
```

Salve-o como **`nova-branch.cmd`** em uma pasta da sua preferência:

```
C:\Scripts\nova-branch.cmd
```

Teste o arquivo em lote executando no terminal `cmd` do windows:

```
C:\Scripts\nova-branch.cmd meuprojeto
```

> Branch **meuprojetoset** up to track remote branch master from origin by rebasing.
>
> Switched to branch '**meuprojeto**' Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Se você quiser fixar na variáveis de ambiente faça:

```
SETX PATH "%PATH%;C:\Scripts"
```

Depois basta chamar o aquivo de criação passando o nome da `branch` como parâmetro:

```
nova-branch.cmd projetoX
```

---

#### Referência:

- https://www.windows-commandline.com/set-path-command-line/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19595067/git-add-commit-and-push-commands-in-one

Answer (score 5):

Conforme colocado pela [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/433981/69296), você pode utilizar o comando `alias`. No entanto, essa abordagem só te permite criá-los em ambientes que possuam esse comando. O Windows, por exemplo, ficaria de fora.

Contudo, o Git também te dá opção de definir *aliases* utilizando uma interface própria. Isso significa que você ainda precisará usar o comando `git` para acessá-los.

Por exemplo, para criar um *alias* `git ac`, que rode os comandos `git add .` e `git commit`, você pode fazer:

```sh
#           Criamos um alias com nome "ac"
#                         ↓↓
git config --global alias.ac '!git add . && git commit'
```

Vale notar que como não passamos nenhuma mensagem para o `commit`, ele irá abrir um editor para que você possa inserir uma mensagem. Além disso, o ponto de exclamação foi utilizado no começo para que seja possível a execução de comandos externos, já que, por padrão, você só pode criar aliases para um subcomando já existente. Por exemplo:

```sh
git config --global alias.l 'log --oneline --abbrev'
```

Note que não precisamos sequer ter colocado o `git` na frente do `log`.

---

Para saber mais, leia [a documentação](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases). Há também um [excelente Gist](https://gist.github.com/kelvinst/331aff32508e2517afbd) sobre o assunto, em português.

Answer (score 2):

Esse resposta não é completa pq fica faltando o `status`

mas dando um:

`git commit -am "sua mensagem"`

Vc vai está fazendo de forma resumida

```
git add .
git commit -m
```

O que resolveria 66,66% do problema :D

De qq forma não vejo muito sentido em vc tem um comando de `status` automático junto com um `commit`, pois mesmo se vc veja algo errado no `status` ai já será tarde de mais. Eu manteria o `git status` sempre individual por uma questão de segurança!

Mas se vc quiser faze

```
git add .
git commit -m "sua mensagem"
git push
```

Com uma linha esse vai funcionar

```
git commit -am "sua mensagem" && git push
```

Inclusive vc pode concatenar o `git status` também com esse `&&`, ai ficaria 100% do jeito que vc quer....

`git status && git commit -am "sua mensagem`

**(mas cuidado para não colocar nada indesejado no `stage`)**